# Problem with watching video on laptop

Tags: laptop, video

**I'm having trouble with opening some of my video files (so far, I noticed .avi).

When I open a folder containing video files, Windows Explorer shuts down everything I had openned, every programa and folder, with a message "... has encountered a problem and needs to close".

When I open 'More information', it says:

"Error signature -
AppName: explorer.exe;
AppVer: 6.0.2900.2649;
ModName: xvid.dll;
ModVer: 0.0.0.0;
Offset: 00033633"

My laptop is Acer Aspire 5720Z.

**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seen this loads of times!

By default, when you see a video, Windows Explorer tries to show a preview / snapshot / picture from the movie.

If you have a currupt codec somewhere, this can cause Explorer to crash every time it trys to generate the preview.

If you have any codec packs installed, try to un-install them or just find the currupt one.

You may need to go around event viewer to find the module name of the one that is causing problems, Personally, I encountered a whole waive of this issue a few years ago with something called DIVX shadow, or something along those lines.

If not having much luck, you can take a look in system information and expand Components > Multimeda > Video Codecs, This should list the location and file name of all codecs on your system. Generally the Microsoft ones are ok, so just Google all the non Microsoft ones you have to see if anyone else reports the same or similar issue.

Comment: The preview mode should be turned off for better performance and lower risk.

Comment: I found the list of video codecs and for one of them manufacturer was unknown, so I deleted it and that solved the problem!

Thank you very much!